# ESP8266 Micropython: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED\r\n') after some time

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, micropython

I am having issues running the following script for a longer period of time:

I use ampy to execute the script on the ESP:

```
sudo ampy --port /dev/ttyUSB0 run photoresistor.py
```

photoresistor.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import machine
import network
from time import sleep
from urllib.urequest import urlopen
import json

wifiap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
wifiap.active(False)
routercon = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
routercon.active(True)
routercon.ifconfig(('10.0.0.128','255.255.255.0','10.0.0.138','10.0.0.138'))
routercon.connect('mywifi', '123')
while not routercon.isconnected():
    pass

posturl=('http://10.0.0.156:23102/rest/v2/send')

adc = machine.ADC(0)
gc.enable()

while True:
    value = adc.read()
    if value < 200:
       message = {'username': 'test', 'message': value, 'chatid': 'test', 'password': 'test', 'notifyself': 'false'}
       r = urlopen(posturl, data=json.dumps(message).encode())
       r.close()
    gc.collect()
    sleep(1)
```

It works as expected in the beginning but after some time I get the following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ampy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ampy/cli.py", line 337, in run
    output = board_files.run(local_file, not no_output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ampy/files.py", line 303, in run
    out = self._pyboard.execfile(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ampy/pyboard.py", line 273, in execfile
    return self.exec_(pyfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ampy/pyboard.py", line 267, in exec_
    raise PyboardError('exception', ret, ret_err)
ampy.pyboard.PyboardError: ('exception', b'', b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "<stdin>", line 28, in <module>\r\n  File "urequests.py", line 152, in post\r\n  File "urequests.py", line 89, in request\r\nOSError: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED\r\n')
```

No idea what to do.
I tried to play around with the garbage collection but it didn't help.

I suspect that the board doesn't clean up sockets properly.
If the board is sending post requests quickly in the loop (every second for 1 minute) and let it sit afterwards for a short period of time it fails quickly with above ECONNABORTED.

If the board sends post requests more slowly (like 2 in a minute) it takes way longer for it to fail. To conclude: I suspect the OS does not properly clean up resources and still has active connections after `r.close()` or I am overseeing something in the code.

I am not sure what else I can do to make sure these sockets are closed.

EDIT:
I found out it fails on connect (https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/urllib.urequest/urllib/urequest.py):

line 28:

```
s.connect(ai[-1])
```

however `routercon.isconnected()` returns true:

```
>>> routercon.isconnected()
True
>>>
```

How can it be that altough there is a active connection I am unable to send an http post request?

EDIT2:

When this happens sometimes I also can't post to another endpoint e.g. the test server with the same webservice

```
>>> r = urlopen(posturl, data=json.dumps(message).encode())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "urllib/urequest.py", line 28, in urlopen
OSError: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED
>>> r = urlopen("http://10.0.0.8:23102/rest/v2/send", data=json.dumps(message).encode())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "urllib/urequest.py", line 28, in urlopen
OSError: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED
>>>
```

Interestingly a http get to google works:

```
>>> r = urlopen("http://www.google.com")
>>>
```

If I let it sit idle for some time http post start to work again.
Could it be that the OS is performing a cleanup in the background?

Comment: It looks to me like your server is not responding. On your dev machine run a loop to post every second sand see if you can reproduce the issue. Are you also overwhelm the server? Another thing to look at are the logs on the server itself.

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is no performance issue with the webservice.

I tried to spam my webservice for 10 minutes straight with 1 request per second - perfectly fine

If I let the ESP8266 sit idle afterwards for some time, I get ECONNABORTED.

However interestingly if I use the domain pointing to the exact same webservice I am able to POST again. e.g. this does not work:

r = urlopen("http://10.0.0.156:23102/rest/v2/send", data=json.dumps(message).encode())

This works:

r = urlopen("http://webservice.ddns.net:23102/rest/v2/send", data=json.dumps(message).encode())

Comment: Is there anything else running on your board, especially something with an interupt involved? If you're catching button presses or triggering on movement... could cause off behavior. This is a bit of a stretch though... 

Another thought... what if you handle the error using try: except: will the request work the next time? I am also suspecting maybe garbage collection is at play here.. you're generating a lot of new strings each round. What is you moved those out as Constants and reused the memory.

Comment: In your try: except: you coudl also call Garbage Collection... http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/speed_python.html#controlling-gc  <<-- other related good reads on this page

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Restarting your api endpoint device will solve the issue.